# Get and use all elements and attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know you can get all the elements by a `$("*")` command using jQuery, but then suppose I wanted to traverse that list and pull a certain element **from that list**, how do I find that  item?  All I get from that is `[object Object]`.  How do I look inside that object set?

Also, does the `$("*")` grab all of the attributes associated with each element?  If not, how do I get those as well.

My purpose is this, if I modify some data using the "Inspect Element" thing in Chrome, I want to get all of the HTML of the page, after the modifications have been made, so as to essentially get a copy of the *new* HTML page.

Comment: You can right click on the container element and click on `Copy as HTML` and you will get new updated HTML in your `clipboard` which you can `paste` anywhere you needed.

Answer (score 0):

> I wanted to traverse that list and pull a certain element from that
>   list, how do I find that item? All I get from that is [object Object].
>   How do I look inside that object set?

You would use `jQuery.each()`

> Also, does the $("*") grab all of the attributes associated with each
>   element?

Yes it does.

**Example:**

```
$("*").each(function(i, v){
  // get tag name
  console.log($(this).get(v).tagName); // or nodeName
  // get node type
  console.log($(this).get(v).nodeType);

  // based on element type, you can get attributes using attr()/prop()
});
```

Comment: @Matt try my update.  I think Blaster just confused the *i* and *v* parameters (very easy to do).

Answer (score 0):

In the console you get sometimes [object Object]. To look inside the object set type:

```
console.dir($('*'));
```

Now you can 'open' the object in your console.

If you want to look for an element and your are not sure, if the element exists you can also:

```
if ($('#IDofTheElement').length > 0) { // Do something with it }
```